# Can't compile/build with Qt 5.2 on ArchLinux

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, clang, archlinux

> 01:31:31: Running steps for project untitled...
>
> 01:31:31: Starting: "/usr/lib/qt/bin/qmake"
>   /root/untitled/untitled.pro -r -spec linux-clang CONFIG+=debug
>   CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
>
> 01:31:31: The process "/usr/lib/qt/bin/qmake" exited normally.
>
> **01:31:31: Could not start process "make"  Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop) When executing step
>   'Make'**
>
> 01:31:31: Elapsed time: 00:00.

I get the above error when i run a defauly untouched untitled project and any other project. I am using Qt creator 3 with Qt 5.2 . I have tried using Clang and GCC compilers, but both have the same error.  I am unable to find any relevant information on the forums, so do help.

Comment: You do have `make` installed, right? Or better, all of `base-devel`.

Comment: Try to build a simple project from command line first

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably havent got an utility called MAKE. 
You can install it: apt-get install make

Comment: -1 from me because `apt-get install make` is for Debian-based distribution. Plus, there was no additional information whatsoever.